# Snowpipe Infastructure & s3 subfolders

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up scalable snowpipe infrastructure. I have one AWS lambda function pulling data and putting the raw json files into their corresponding folders below.

Ideally I'd like to set up snowpipe to read in the data from each folder into it's own Snowflake table.

Ex)

- The leads json file living in the leads folder is now piped into a
  leads_json table within snowflake.
- The opportunities json file living in the opportunities folder is now piped into a opportunitie_json table within snowflake.

How do I go about setting up the pipelines and stages to reduce the number of pipelines and stages needed?

Will I need one pipeline and stage per sub folder in the bucket?

I'm going to make use out of the AUTO_INGEST=true feature using SQS notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 1 PIPE for each TABLE that you are loading via Snowpipe.  You could have a single STAGE pointing to the top folder of your S3 bucket, if you wish, or you could create 1 per table at a lower level folder.  I hope that is answering your question.

Comment: Adding on to Mike's answer; I recommend a single storage integration for the credentials, so they are not on a per stage basis, and one stage for each of the AWS folders you have listed.  This can reduce the files a stage has access to and can help reduce overhead if you must reprocess a set of files.

Comment: @Chris as in Option 1 of this documentation? Currently I've only done Option 2. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html#option-2-configuring-an-aws-iam-role

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton

Comment: @Bigmoose70 Yes, exactly. It does require ACCOUNTADMIN access to create the integration.

Comment: @Chris I went ahead with option 1! When creating the pipes I get one sqs id for 4 pipes. Is that normal, I was under the impression it would be one sqs id per pipe.

Comment: @Chris figured it out! Thanks for all your help! Can't wait for them to come out with a way to do tasks based off of events rather than a cron or another task.

Comment: @Bigmoose70 The events you are looking for are sort of already there, actually.  Check out streams and the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA function.  These allow a task to execute more frequently, but will only actually run something if there is new data.  Not exactly a "trigger event" but serves the purpose well.

Comment: @MikeWalton hmm I will check that out. Currently I am truncating the whole table in snowflake every time a new data file is pulled into s3. So instead of only appending new lines I am replacing all of them. I know i know I need to figure out how to do it more effectively.